# Sharepoint SE resource reservation calendar

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I want to create simple room booking site on SharePoint subscription edition.
I found that I can add Reservation content type to calendar and achieve this functionality.
The problem is that I don't know how to add resources:

[image: form]

I've created a new list and added Resource and Resource group content types:

[image: resource content type]

Added two resources and one resource group

[image: resources]

but they still don't appear on the form.
Maybe there should be some special kind of list but I don't have it.

How can I add resources to choose from on the calendar reservation form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it doesn't work this way, I need to have Group Work site template and a site based on that template, then I can have group calendar with resources.

So I enabled Group Work Site like this:
Go to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\1033\XML, open WEBTEMP.XML file, find an element with 'Group Work Site' title attribute and change its Hidden attribute from TRUE to FALSE.
Got this info from here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/588685/Reservation-of-Resources-in-SharePoint-and-SharePo